# How do you get the older Mac OSX SDKs for Xcode?

Tags: xcode, macos

How can I can the 10.6 version of MacOSX SDK with the latest version of the Xcode (version 4.6)?

Comment: Why would you need this?

Comment: I am trying to compile an old application and somehow, the latest version of MacOSX 10.8 SDK is breaking it with the following error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/usr/include/ucontext.h:43:2: error: The deprecated ucontext routines require _XOPEN_SOURCE to be defined
#error The deprecated ucontext routines require _XOPEN_SOURCE to be defined  What should I do to solve this?

Comment: See my answer for a suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would have to install an older Xcode, take `MacOSX10.6.sdk` out of the SDK folder at the location it's installed (default: `/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs`) and copy it to the SDK folder in your latest Xcode.app (default: `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs`).

---

As for fixing your error, try importing/including `<sys/ucontext.h>` instead of Apple's `ucontext.h`.